# Running sudo in shell script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am just creating a little script which changes mac address. Everytime I run it i have to enter sudo password. How to allow script to enter password or skip sudo verification?
OR is there another way to create this script?Maybe use python?
So here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli radio wifi off
sudo macchanger wlp6s0 -a
nmcli radio wifi on
```

Comment: Take a look: `man visudo` and `man sudo.conf`

Comment: You can launch your script with `sudo ./yourscript`, so all commands inside  will run as sudo as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is modify the `sudoers` file to allow the user running the script access to a specific command without having to enter a password.

See this answer for more information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands

In short, call `visudo` and add the following entry:

```
your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/the/binary/macchanger wlp6s0 -a
```

Of course, exchange `/path/to/the/binary/macchanger` with the true path, found by running `which macchanger`.

Now the user `your_user` can run that single command with those exact arguments via `sudo` without password.

Also, as Cyrus pointed out, `man` is your friend. It's a good idea to *always* check the manpages first. More often than not you're going to find the answer to your question by reading it and trying some ideas. In this case: `man visudo` and `man sudo.conf`.

Comment: The problem it loose all portability, requiring extra configuration as root.

Comment: Indeed, but portability was not what OP was asking for. Also, `sudo` is a system-level command. Of course it needs configuration as root.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing around with `sudo` and risking giving full root
access to programs that may act irresponsibly you can set
`cap_net_admin` on the binary:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_admin+ep "$(command -v macchanger)"
```

It's just one-time operation. Now you can remove `sudo` from your
script and it will work.

> Maybe use python?

No, that wouldn't help.  Language doesn't matter.  It's kernel that
allows or forbids performing certain operations.